# Java - LWJGL OBJ Loader with Materials not rendering

Tags: opengl, java, rendering, lwjgl, materials

So I successfully loading my obj file but I obviously want to get materials on it. I added the vt(texture) to the OBJLoader and the Model.render but still rendering textureless. I have exported the file from Blender with UV unwrap so the materials and vt are appearing in the obj file. Do I need to do something with the mtl file? if so, how so?

Model.java

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.*;

public class Model {
    public List<Vector3f> vertices;
    public List<Vector3f> normals;
    public List<Face> faces;
    public List<Vector2f> texcoords;

    public static Model getModel(String s) throws IOException{
        return new Model(s);
    }

    private Model(String path) throws IOException {
        vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        faces = new ArrayList<Face>();
        texcoords = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        new OBJLoader(this, path);
    }

    public void render(){
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (Face face : faces) {

            Vector3f n1 = normals.get((int) face.normal.x -1);
            Vector2f t1 = texcoords.get((int) face.texcoord.x -1);
            Vector3f v1 = vertices.get((int) face.vertex.x -1);

            Vector3f n2 = normals.get((int) face.normal.y -1);
            Vector2f t2 = texcoords.get((int) face.texcoord.y -1);
            Vector3f v2 = vertices.get((int) face.vertex.y -1);

            Vector3f n3 = normals.get((int) face.normal.z -1);
            Vector2f t3 = texcoords.get((int) face.texcoord.z -1);
            Vector3f v3 = vertices.get((int) face.vertex.z -1);

            glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
            glTexCoord2f(t1.x, t1.y);
            glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);

            glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
            glTexCoord2f(t2.x, t2.y);
            glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);

            glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
            glTexCoord2f(t3.x, t3.y);
            glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

OBJLoader.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.*;

public class OBJLoader {

    public OBJLoader(Model m, String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
        String line;
        while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("v ")){
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.vertices.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
            }
            if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.normals.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
            }
            if (line.startsWith("vt ")){
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                m.texcoords.add(new Vector2f(x,y));
            }
            if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                Vector3f vertexIndices = new Vector3f(
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]), 
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]));
                Vector3f normalIndices = new Vector3f(
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]), 
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]));
                Vector3f textureIndices = new Vector3f(
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]), 
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[1]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[1]));
                m.faces.add(new Face(vertexIndices, normalIndices, textureIndices));
            }
        }
        read.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Resulting render of Code]

Comment: I really recommend looking into modern OpenGL such as vertex buffers;  immediate mode is heavily outdated by today's standards.

Comment: I'd recommend learning good java practises, such as using switches.

Comment: Do you load in a texture before you render the tree?

Answer (score 0):

look at exported obj file, there you'll see directives about:
1. import mtl file
mtllib "mtl file name"
2. and use materials 
usemtl "material nae"

mtl, obj format are described here 
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/